# Issue in JSON Decode

Tags: php, json

Hi I am getting a weird issue in JSON decode, JSON is getting decoded correctly locally, but on my server the json_decode function returns NULL.

This is the JSON that I am posting from my test page:

```
[
  {
    "pictureTaken": 0,
    "unit_id": 20192,
    "id": 2,
    "deficiency_id": 155,
    "last_modifier_id": 4,
    "comments": "Living room",
    "level": 3,
    "location": "Living room",
    "property_id": 26,
    "inspectable_item_id": 44,
    "building_id": -769876698
  }  
]
```

now when I do `var_dump(json_deocde($_POST['data'], true));` I get NULL response.

when I do `echo $_POST['data'];` I get:

```
[ { \"pictureTaken\": 0, \"unit_id\": 20192, \"id\": 2, \"deficiency_id\": 155, \"last_modifier_id\": 4, \"comments\": \"Living room\", \"level\": 3, \"location\": \"Living room\", \"property_id\": 26, \"inspectable_item_id\": 44, \"building_id\": -769876698 } ]
```

I think due to these `\"` json_decode is not working, kindly help me in fixing this issue,

Some Server Info:

PHP Version 5.2.17
json version    1.2.1

Answer (score 3):

You have [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled on your server. Disable them.

Comment: According to the PHP docs, magic quotes are deprecated. This guy is using an old version of PHP. Time to upgrade.

Comment: @Moshe, i am using BlueHost hosting, and they are using PHP Version 5.2.17, so i can not do anything on PHP version...

Comment: Ugh, I used to use BlueHost. I can't recommend them because of how they will shut down your site without warning at the first sign of even trying to use the "unlimited" stuff they offer you. If you're looking for a reliable, no-nonsense host, try [TSOHost](http://billing.tsohost.co.uk/aff.php?aff=638)

Answer (score 0):

you can always do this :
var_dump(json_deocde(str_replace("\",$_POST['data']), true));

that would remove the slashes from your json string